# How to make one axis scrollable while other is only visible?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div contains multiple blocks,
I want them to overflow on the x-axis and not scrollable but scrollable on the y-axis.

It is quite hard to explain... but you can keep up with this link
it has comments on it.

https://jsfiddle.net/qzenn/ofjzw5h8/16/

```css
body {
  background-color: #212529;
}

#side-navbar {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #2b3035;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5%;
  /* I tried this,
    which changed the side of the scrollbar
    but didn't solve the issue 
    direction: rtl; 
    */
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: visible;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  /* if you delete the 3 lines above you will 
    see what I wanted to do,
    but it just scrolls the whole page then...*/
}

.nav-block {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 12%;
  transition: all ease 0.2s;
}

.nav-block:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="side-navbar">

  <div class="nav-block"></div>
  <div class="nav-block"></div>
  <div class="nav-block"></div>
  <div class="nav-block"></div>
  <div class="nav-block"></div>
  <div class="nav-block"></div>
  <div class="nav-block"></div>
  <div class="nav-block"></div>
  <div class="nav-block"></div>
  <div class="nav-block"></div>
  <div class="nav-block"></div>
  <div class="nav-block"></div>
  <div class="nav-block"></div>
  <div class="nav-block"></div>
  <div class="nav-block"></div>
  <div class="nav-block"></div>
  <div class="nav-block"></div>
  <div class="nav-block"></div>


</div>
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x-axis not overflowing according to your code. Since nav-block has width 100%. It's taking entire width of parent div.
y-axis scroll bar has some width which is overriding div block.

Minimise the scroll bar width and make nav-block width as 80% or lesser